# How to disable/toggle touchpad in 16.04 on ASUS ROG GL552 laptop

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, laptop, asus

On my old laptop I use this script to disable/enable touchpad:

```
(lsmod | grep psmouse > /dev/null) && sudo rmmod psmouse || sudo modprobe psmouse
```

but this script don't work anymore on ASUS ROG GL522, how can I disable/enable touchpad in this laptop?

lsmod show those modules:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
psmouse               118784  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  0
mmc_block              32768  0
uas                    20480  1
usb_storage            57344  1 uas
cpuid                  16384  0
btrfs                1003520  0
xor                    28672  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
ufs                    73728  0
qnx4                   16384  0
hfsplus                94208  0
hfs                    57344  0
minix                  32768  0
ntfs                  102400  0
msdos                  20480  0
jfs                   180224  0
xfs                   888832  0
libcrc32c              16384  1 xfs
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               352256  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
drbg                   28672  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  2
i915                 1130496  0
bnep                   20480  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_conexant    20480  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
joydev                 20480  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
uvcvideo               77824  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
coretemp               16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec         118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
nvidia_modeset        741376  0
snd_hda_core           61440  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel             167936  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
kvm                   479232  1 kvm_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
videodev              155648  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
arc4                   16384  2
snd_pcm                94208  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               24576  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            28672  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                57344  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
iwlmvm                294912  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
btusb                  40960  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
mac80211              659456  1 iwlmvm
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
aesni_intel            20480  4
nvidia               9109504  1 nvidia_modeset
aes_i586               20480  1 aesni_intel
snd                    69632  20 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
xts                    16384  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  2 lrw,xts
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
cryptd                 20480  1 ablk_helper
iwlwifi               176128  1 iwlmvm
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              16384  1 snd
cfg80211              499712  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
hci_uart               81920  0
input_leds             16384  0
btbcm                  16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
serio_raw              16384  0
btintel                16384  2 btusb,hci_uart
shpchp                 32768  0
idma64                 20480  0
bluetooth             479232  11 bnep,btbcm,btqca,btrtl,btusb,hci_uart,btintel
mei_me                 28672  0
elan_i2c               32768  0
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
mei                    94208  1 mei_me
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
int3403_thermal        16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_lpss_pci         16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
acpi_pad               16384  0
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
tpm_crb                16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  2 intel_lpss_pci,intel_lpss_acpi
int3402_thermal        16384  0
int3400_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
i915_bpo             1241088  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        135168  2 i915,i915_bpo
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  77824  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mii                    16384  1 r8169
ahci                   36864  3
drm                   311296  5 i915,i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                    98304  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
pinctrl_sunrisepoint    24576  0
video                  36864  3 i915,i915_bpo,asus_wmi
pinctrl_intel          20480  1 pinctrl_sunrisepoint
fjes                   28672  0
```

psmouse is probably added by that script. Can I onload one of the above modules to disable touchpad if yes then which one?

**EDIT**: output of xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OM                                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: That means that this laptop has a non-ps2 touchpad. I do not see a reason to toggle touchpad by removing or adding a kernel module. You can toggle it by a Fn button in most cases, or in user space.

Comment: @Pilot6 the fn key don't work on my laptop (it work I can assign program to it but the toggle touchpad don't work) so I need a script that will do that. I'll assign it to that key in keybaord settings.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added `xinput` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the touchpad by

```
xinput disable 10
```

Enable it back by

```
xinput enable 10
```

There is no need to fiddle with kernel modules.

You can also check if the device is enabled by

```
xinput list-props 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used this command `(xinput list-props 10 | grep 'Device Enabled' | grep -E ':\s0' > /dev/null) && xinput enable 10 || xinput disable 10`

Comment: I've ended up with this `device=$(xinput list | grep Touchpad | sed -e 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/');
(xinput list-props $device | grep 'Device Enabled' | grep -E ':\s0' > /dev/null) && xinput enable $device || xinput disable $device` because id may change